# can anyone please help me with the sequence of execution of this program

Tags: c, recursion

I was trying to predict the output of this program:

```
#include
void fun(int x)
{
  if (x > 0)
  {
    fun(--x);
    printf("%d\t", x);
    fun(--x);
  }
}

int main()
{
  int a = 4;
  fun(a);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

the output of this program is:

```
0 1 2 0 3 0 1
```

I know its tough to explain in terms but all I want to know is that when 4 is passed as an argument than firstly statement `fun(4--)` i.e. `fun(3)` is executed,so from here does a call to `fun(3)` is made or `3` is printed then `fun(3--)` statement is executed as 
basically I am confused about the sequence in which:

```
fun(--x);
printf("%d\t", x);
fun(--x);
```

these 3 statements are executed.

Comment: With that short a sequence and shallow recursive stack, this should be trivial to draw out on a single sheet of paper with room to spare. Have you done so ?

Comment: thinking of this as a call tree may help; NB a function returns after all the recursive calls return

Comment: A slight modification to your algorithm to include indented function printing would likely answer your question. [See it live](http://ideone.com/n9lk9S).

Comment: Code like this always reminds me of the main purpose of recursion. Which is to teach students recursion, so that when they become teachers one day, they can teach students recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call fun(4):

1. it calls fun(3)
2. fun(3) calls fun(2)
3. fun(2) calls fun(1)
4. fun(1) calls fun(0)
5. fun(0) ends doing nothing
6. it comes back in fun(1), where x has becomed 0 from --x and displays it, and calls fun(-1), which does nothing. Now fun(1) finished its job
7. it comes back in fun(2), displays 1 and calls fun(0), which does nothing. Now fun(2) finished its job.
8. it comes back in fun(3), displays 2 and calls fun(1). As explained above, fun(1) displays 0.
9. it comes back in fun(4), displays 3 and calls fun(2). As explained above, fun(2) displays 0 1.

I hope this clarifies things a bit for you.

Answer (score 5):

What happens is:

```
call to fun(4)
    -> call to fun(3)
        -> call to fun(2)
            -> call to fun(1)
                -> call to fun(0) which prints nothing and returns
                -> printing 0
                -> call to fun(-1) which prints nothing and returns
            <- execution returns to fun(2), where 1 is printed
        -> in fun(3) 2 is printed and fun(1) called
            -> fun(1) prints 0
            <-
        <-
    -> in fun(4) 3 is printed and fun(2) called
        -> fun(2) prints 0 1
```

Usually it is a good practice to observe the behavior of calls with elementary arguments, i.e. in your case:

- `fun(x)` where `x <= 0` - skips condition, returns, nothing is printed
- `fun(1)` - calls `fun(0)`, prints `0`, calls `fun(-1)` - i.e. prints `0`
- `fun(2)` - calls `fun(1)` which prints `0`, prints `1`, calls `fun(0)` - i.e. prints `0 1`

Then you can draw on paper the flow of execution and when you see one of these 3, you already know the result. Like in my example above, at the end when I saw `fun(2)` I looked what happened before when `fun(2)` was called and saw "ah yeah, `fun(2)` prints `0 1`". Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Flow:

```
main():
 fun(4):
 x is 3 and the following are called-
  fun(3):
  x is 2 and-
   fun(2):
   x is 1 and-
    fun(1):
    x is 0
    the call to fun(0) returns, after having bottomed out, PRINT 0.
    calls fun(-1)
    call returns
   when fun(1) returns, PRINT 1
   x is 0
  PRINT 2
  fun(1)
   x is 0
   call to fun(0) returns
   PRINT 0
   call to fun(-1) returns
 PRINT 3
 fun(3)
  x is 2
  fun(2)
   x is 1
   fun(0) returns
   PRINT 0
  PRINT 1
```

i might have gone wrong, but such is the flow.